# React Native ScrollView/FlatList not scrolling

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo

I have a list of data that I want to place inside a FlatList (i.e. ScrollView) and whenever I try to scroll down to view more of the list, the ScrollView just bounces back up to the top of the list so I cannot ever see the bottom of the list.

I am using Expo and the strange thing is that if I just create a new project or copy/paste some code into Snack then the scrolling works just fine. It is only in my current project that I cannot get the list to scroll. I have even gone into the `main.js` file and just pasted my example code in there and the issue still persists.

My example code is located here: https://snack.expo.io/ryDPtO5-b
I have pasted this exact code into my project and it is not working as expected.

Versions:
RN 0.44 /
Expo SDK 17.0.0 /
React: 16.0.0-alpha.6

My actual use case for my project involves placing a FlatList component at the bottom-third of the screen to show a list of jobs. This is where I discovered the error and when I started to try and debug the issue. In my project I have a parent `View` with a style of `{flex: 1` with a child of `List` that contains the `FlatList`... `List` comes from `react-native-elements`

**EDIT**

Here is the code I am actually trying to use:

```
 <View style={styles.container}>
<View style={containerStyles.headerContainerStyle}>
    <Text style={[textStyles.h2, { textAlign: "center" }]}>
        Territory: {this.props.currentTerritory}
    </Text>
</View>
<View style={styles.mapContainer}>
    <MapView
        provider="google"
        onRegionChangeComplete={this.onRegionChangeComplete}
        region={this.state.region}
        style={{ flex: 1 }}
    >
        {this.renderMapMarkers()}
    </MapView>
</View>
<Badge containerStyle={styles.badgeStyle}>
    <Text>Orders Remaining: {this.props.jobsList.length}</Text>
</Badge>
<List containerStyle={{ flex: 1 }}>
    <FlatList
        data={this.props.jobsList}
        keyExtractor={item => item.id}
        renderItem={this.renderJobs}
        removeClippedSubviews={false}
    />
  </List>
 </View>;
```

And all my styles

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
container: {
    flex: 1,
},
mapContainer: {
    height: 300,
},
badgeStyle: {
    backgroundColor: 'green',
    alignSelf: 'center',
    marginTop: 15,
    width: 300,
    height: 35,
},
});
```

and lastly, my renderItem function:

```
 renderJobs = ({ item }) => {
const { fullAddress, pickupTime } = item;

return (
    <ListItem
        containerStyle={
            item.status === "active" && { backgroundColor: "#7fbf7f" }
        }
        title={fullAddress}
        titleStyle={{ fontSize: 14 }}
        subtitle={pickupTime}
        subtitleStyle={{ fontSize: 12, color: "black" }}
        onPress={() =>
            this.props.navigation.navigate("jobActions", { job: item })
        }
    />
);
};
```

Comment: Do not provide external links to your code. Create an MCVE instead: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 6):

I was able to solve this problem.

The Solution is to use flatlist component  `<View style={{flex:1}}>` after  renderRow return component  `<View style={{flex:1}}>`

Comment: I still have the problem with your solution. My solution : I had to remove the marginTop and marginBottom in renderItem. Do you know why it works now ?

Answer (score 3):

I am confused - are you using a `FlatList` or a `ScrollView` - these two elements have completely different lifecycle events (a `FlatList` requires you to define how individual rows will render and their keys, whereas a `ScrollView` expects the children to be rendered inline with the component).

Regardless, I think the issue is in your structure, it sounds like the `List` element requires a height attribute as well (`{flex: 1}`) as the absolute parent is filling it's space, but the `List` component is not having a pre-defined height.

Comment: I added some more code in my question to help clarify...

I want to use a `FlatList` component but it wasn't working so I tried to test out a regular `ScrollView` in my app, but it also was not working.

I added the `{ flex: 1}` to the list component but that didn't solve the problem...

Comment: Reading about `List` from `react-native-elements` - it itself is a replacement for `FlatList`, not a wrapping component. Either remove the `List` and use `FlatList`, or use the underlying `ListItem` component that `List` is designed to be used with.

Comment: So I tried both solutions. I removed `FlatList` completely and just used `List` and then mapped over the data set returning a `ListItem` for each item in the data set. I then tried just using a `FlatList` component without a parent `List` and just rendered a bunch of `Text` components but still got the error.

I used this blog post as my guide when first implementing this solution: https://medium.com/react-native-development/how-to-use-the-flatlist-component-react-native-basics-92c482816fe6

I got it to work just fine in a new project but not my existing one...

Answer (score 0):

So after debugging this a bit more today and I ended up just creating a brand new Expo project and copy/pasting all my source code into the new project, changing my Github project name to the new name, and setting the remote origin to my github repo (the one where I changed the name) on my new local project.

For some reason there appeared to be a problem with the Expo project. It almost seemed like the actual `NAME` of the project was causing issues as I attempted to change the NEW project's name to that of the original project, but it didn't work. It only worked when doing a brand new project, but using the exact same source code.