# How to Scroll Right To Columns in React Native FlatList (2018)

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist

I am seeking a way to scroll a viewport over a table like this, except that every cell is exactly the same size: 
[image: viewport can scroll up, right, left, down]

I am currently using `FlatList`'s [`numColumns`](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flatlist.html#numcolumns) parameter to make a table and scroll the viewport over that table.

Here is a Snack example - [RegularGridExample](https://snack.expo.io/r1PjgD-nz):

```
import React from 'react';
import { FlatList, Text, View } from 'react-native';

const numRows = 10,
  numColumns = 10,
  width = 100,
  height = 100,
  cells = [...Array(numRows * numColumns)].map((_, cellIndex) => {
    const rowIndex = Math.floor(cellIndex / numRows),
      colIndex = cellIndex % numColumns;
    return {
      key: `${colIndex},${rowIndex}`,
      rowIndex,
      colIndex,
      styles: {
        width,
        height,
        backgroundColor: 'green',
        borderColor: 'black',
        borderWidth: 1,
      },
    };
  });

export default class RegularGridExample extends React.Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <FlatList
        data={cells}
        renderItem={this.renderItem}
        numColumns={numColumns}
        horizontal={false}
        columnWrapperStyle={{
          borderColor: 'black',
          width: numColumns * width,
        }}
      />
    );
  }

  renderItem = ({ item: { styles, rowIndex, colIndex } }) => {
    return (
      <View style={styles}>
        <Text>r{rowIndex}</Text>
        <Text>c{colIndex}</Text>
      </View>
    );
  };
}
```

This example will correctly scroll to reveal the rows below the viewport, but it will not scroll to reveal the columns beyond the viewport. How can I enable scrolling the viewport to reveal a `FlatList`'s columns?

### Update 1

I do not think this can be easily solved with nested `FlatList`s, which is the first thing I tried before using the `numColumns` approach above. The use case here is shifting the viewport over a grid that's larger than the viewport, not just scrolling one row within the viewport.

### Update 2

I'm seeking a virtualized solution. While the wireframe above uses text, the use case I'm actually interested in is browsing a tile server navigating over portions of a large 50MB+ image. It will be too slow to load all of them into a scroll view.

### Unrelated Stack Overflow Posts

- [React Native ScrollView/FlatList not scrolling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44253823/react-native-scrollview-flatlist-not-scrolling) - this is about adding flex to the viewport to enable scrolling along the major axis of the `FlatList`, which is already working in the example above. My concern is scrolling along the `crossAxis`.
- [React native flatlist not scrolling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49426115/react-native-flatlist-not-scrolling) - it is unclear what the expected and actual behavior is here
- [How can I sync two flatList scroll position in react native](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48057527/how-can-i-sync-two-flatlist-scroll-position-in-react-native) - here, the poster is seeking to simulate masonry layout; I'm not doing anything so fancy

Comment: Currently, you want two way scrolling, but it won't be possible with numColumns styling. You might need two FlatLists or two ScrollViews or a mixture of both, whatever is suitable.

Answer (score 1):

This can't be done using the `FlatList` method, since `numColumns` is used which explicitly sets `horizontal={false}`, hence *disabling the scrolling horizontal direction*.

Here's a workaround by using `nested ScrollViews`

```
export default class RegularGridExample extends React.Component {
    render() {
        const generatedArray = [1,2,3,4,5,6]

        return (
            <ScrollView horizontal>
                <ScrollView >
                    {generatedArray.map((data, index) => {
                       return <View style={{flexDirection: 'row'}} >
                           {generatedArray.map((data, index) => {
                              return  <View style={{height: 100, width: 100, backgroundColor: 'red', borderWidth: 1, borderColor: 'black'}} />
                           })}
                       </View>
                    })}
                </ScrollView>
            </ScrollView>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your post. Unfortunately, I don't think nested `FlatList`s solve the use case: a grid which is larger than the viewport on both X and Y needs to be able to move the entire viewport *over* the grid in either dimension. With nested `FlatList`s, a vertical swipe moves the viewport correctly up and down, but a horizontal swipe scrolls only a single row.

Comment: Yes, but since you're using numColumns prop therefore horizontal scrolling is locked and wont be possible in a Flatlist as mentioned in the docs. I'll figure something in the meanwhile.

Comment: Interesting, I didn't see anything in the docs suggesting horizontal scrolling was locked with `numColumns` prop. Can you provide a link? Here is [the `numColumns` documentation I've seen](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flatlist.html#numcolumns): *"Multiple columns can only be rendered with horizontal={false} and will zig-zag like a flexWrap layout. Items should all be the same height - masonry layouts are not supported."* That doesn't suggest to me that scrolling will be disabled.

Comment: horizontal={false} on the FlatList inherited ScrollView prop means it cant be scrolled horizontally. _When true, the scroll view's children are arranged horizontally in a row instead of vertically in a column. The default value is false._

Comment: Here's the link to [`ScrollView.horizontal`](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/scrollview.html#horizontal) with the quote you mentioned. I think I see what you mean - by marking it as `horizontal={false}` I'm actively disabling the scrolling in the horizontal direction. Thanks for pointing me to this.

Comment: I'll try this out. I may end up trying a ScrollView, but I was hoping to get virtualized support, because my actual use case is building a tile image browser like Google Maps for navigating huge images.